# No FileSystem for scheme: null

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to run a jar (maven project) using "hadoop -jar" and i get the error "No FileSystem for scheme". I have been reading about this error on stackoverflow and it seems like the problem is inside the META-INF/services/org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem. Mine looks like this:

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem
org.apache.hadoop.fs.viewfs.ViewFileSystem
org.apache.hadoop.fs.ftp.FTPFileSystem
org.apache.hadoop.fs.HarFileSystem
```

HDFS lines are missing. 
This is part of my code:

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {   
     Configuration conf=getConf();    conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl",org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());       conf.set("fs.file.impl",org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName()); 
       args = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();       
     Job job = Job.getInstance(conf,"Count");
     job.setInputFormatClass(ImageBundleInputFormat.class);
     job.setMapperClass(CountMapper.class);
     job.setReducerClass(CountReducer.class);
     job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
     job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
     job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
     job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
     FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
     FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
     job.addCacheFile(new URI("//path/lbpcascade_frontalcatface.xml"));
     job.setJarByClass(Count.class);
     boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
     return success ? 0 : 1;
   }

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


       ToolRunner.run(new Count(), args);
       System.exit(0);
   }
```

The error is at line  boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the filesystems implementations in your job unless you wan't to override something.

Where are your cluster configuration files ? (hdfs-site.xml, core-site.xml, etc.)

Be sure that your  HADOOP_CONF_DIR environment variable is pointng to them and they are configured properly.

What is your configuration for **fs.defaultFS** property ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and spent a lot of time trying to debug through issue. In my case I was using spark mlib on windows and the code was primarily

sparksess = SparkSession.builder.appName("..").config("spark.master","local[*])....

sparksess.creatDataFrame(..)

The resolution was the spark.local.dir and spark.sql.warehouse.dir in the spark session builder should be specifying the path in specific format for windows something like ///D:/sparkworkdir worked for me.  Hope saves someone some time